# php - multidimensional array regex search and print out partial array to look at structure

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array structure, it is stored in a variable $xxx

```
Array
(
    [xyz] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [0] => s
        )

    [d2s] => Array
        (
            [a] => 96
            [d] => 4

         )
...
)
```

It is a long array, and I don't want to out put the whole thing, how do print only the first 5 (1st dimension) values along with the 2nd dimension values?

Secondly, if I want this array to contain only alphabets in the FIRST dimension, how do I either delete values that don't match that requirement or retain values that match the requirement?  so that my final array would be

```
Array
(
    [xyz] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [0] => s
        )

...
)
```

TIA

Comment: @josh, I tried  foreach ($main as $val), and then match pattern against $val, if no match, unset($main[$val]), but I get the error saying that expected $val as a string but it is an array.

Comment: I offered a solution, but it would be best to provide the code you're having trouble with along with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output only the first 5 elements, use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
array_slice($arr, 0, 5)
```

To remove any elements whose index contains non-alpha characters.

```
foreach ($arr AS $index => $value) {
        // Remove the element if the index contains non-alpha characters
        if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]/', $index))
                unset($arr[$index]);
}
```

[Check it out in action.](http://ideone.com/HmEw3)

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the code, I actually did the 2nd part of the code exactly the same way you just did and it works.  As for the first part, I meant to say print out the 1st dimension value and the 2nd dimension values (I left out the 'dimension' in my original question, sorry).  I was basically looking for a quick way of using print_r, something like print_r ($arr,0,5), but I guest that function does not exist.  Thanks again.

Comment: That makes more sense. A native function does exist for what you're looking for. I've updated the solution accordingly.

Comment: haha, array slice, doh! moment for me, and to think I have been using print_r and waiting like a fool for the output to print all these times.